# iOS: Mute AVAudio when playing embedded clip in WebView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudiosession

In my app in I am using AVAudioSession to play an audio stream, which starts automatically playback when application starts.

At another section of the app if the user navigates there is a webview which might contain an embeded clip either from youtube, soundcloud whatever might contain a sound.
I want the main audio stream to pause in case the user selects to play that sound which is in the webview. Right now if the user selects to play the clip in the webview the sound is mixed which is annoying and the user has to mannualy pause the main stream. 
Is there a way to prevent that? I need to mute or pause the main stream in case the user selects to hear the embedded clip.

What I am using in AppDelegate is the following:

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

Comment: hi, did you manage to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You need subscribe to [AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616596-interruptionnotification) where you can stop play your audio

*Swift 4.2*

### Subscribe to notification

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleAudioSessionInterruption), name: AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification, object: AVAudioSession.sharedInstance())
```

### Handle notification

```
@objc func handleAudioSessionInterruption(_ notification : Notification) {
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }
    guard let rawInterruptionType = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? NSNumber else { return }
    guard let interruptionType = AVAudioSession.InterruptionType(rawValue: rawInterruptionType.uintValue) else { return }

    switch interruptionType {
    case .began:
        //stop play your audio
    case .ended: //interruption ended
        //do something if needed
    }
}
```

**2.** This only works on the device. Don't test on simulator